# Button not visible in a div with padding, flex and position

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am learning some React from a course Maximilian Schwarzmuller created. It seems like some of the styles are not working. Tried to figure out why but I still don't have an idea.

Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-montalcini-3urgmm

Basically Max uses position fixed to stick the header to the top of the website, then he uses flexbox to align items and justify content - space-between to have the button on the right side of the site. He also sets up a padding to move button and h1 header closer to the centre.
If I remove padding it looks ok but then I need to find a way to make those items closer to centre. This becomes an issue.

I know that I can use some workaround but I would like to make it work as Max did. (Maybe he cheated :D )

Comment: You can go with a combination of `space-around`/`center` and padding/margin on your flex children.

Comment: Your `.header` class has `width: 100%;` with `padding: 0 10%;`. Due to traditional `content-box` sizing model, it'll end up bigger than 100% of viewport width. (See this [MDN doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for reference). In short, you could either add `box-sizing: border-box;` OR replace `width: 100%;` with `right: 0;` to ensure the full viewport width. No need for adjusting flex styles.

Comment: @BumhanYu Thanks for clarifying. This is amazing. Thank you. Yet I still wonder how Max made it work in his project :)

Comment: @ZachJensz could you explain more? I imagine that you are saying about doing `space-around` and then when the elements seem to close add padding right to element on the left and padding left on element on the right?

Comment: @Maxrain Yes you are exactly right. Also what Bumhan mentioned is important, it's a good idea to have border-box as a universal default with `* { box-sizing: border-box }`